# Plot over an image background in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, plot, overlap

I'd like to plot a graph over an image. I followed this tutorial to [Plot over an image background in MATLAB](http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/matlab/plot_over_image_background) and it works fine:

```
% replace with an image of your choice
img = imread('myimage.png');

% set the range of the axes
% The image will be stretched to this.
min_x = 0;
max_x = 8;
min_y = 0;
max_y = 6;

% make data to plot - just a line.
x = min_x:max_x;
y = (6/8)*x;

imagesc([min_x max_x], [min_y max_y], img);
hold on;
plot(x,y,'b-*','linewidth',1.5);
```

But when I apply the procedure to my study case, it doesn't work. I'd like to do something like:

```
I = imread('img_png.png');  % here I load the image

DEM = GRIDobj('srtm_bigtujunga30m_utm11.tif');
FD  = FLOWobj(DEM,'preprocess','c');
S = STREAMobj(FD,flowacc(FD)>1000);

% with the last 3 lines I calculated the stream network on a geographic area using the TopoToolBox

imagesc(I);
hold on
plot(S)
```

The aim is to plot the stream network over the satellite image of the same area.
The only difference between the two examples that doesn't let the code working is in the plot line, in the first case "plot(x,y)" works, in the other one "plot(S)" doesn't.

Thanks guys.

[This is the satellite image, imagesc(I)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozjlT.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that the `plot` method of the `STREAMobj` performs it's own custom plotting including creating new figures, axes, toggling `hold` states, etc. Because you can't easily control what their `plot` routine does, it's likely easier to flip the order of your plotting so that you plot your stuff *after* the toolbox plots the `STREAMobj`. This way you have completely control over how your image is added.

```
% Plot the STREAMobj
hlines = plot(S);

% Make sure we plot on the same axes
hax = ancestor(hlines, 'axes');

% Make sure that we can add more plot objects
hold(hax, 'on')

% Plot your image data on the same axes
imagesc(I, 'Parent', hax)
```

Comment: I tried with this code: 

I = imread('img_png.png');  % here I load the image
DEM = GRIDobj('srtm_bigtujunga30m_utm11.tif');
FD  = FLOWobj(DEM,'preprocess','c');
S = STREAMobj(FD,flowacc(FD)>1000);
% Plot the STREAMobj
hlines = plot(S);

% Make sure we plot on the same axes
hax = ancestor(hlines, 'axes');

% Make sure that we can add more plot objects
hold(hax, 'on')

% Plot your image data on the same axes
imagesc(I, 'Parent', hax)

it doesn't works fine, it plot the streamobj in a wrog way without the image.

Comment: @Geonik Please post an *actual* image of the result in your original question.

Comment: I posted the resulting image in my original question

Comment: @Geonik Can you post what the image looks like with just `imagesc`?

Comment: I posted the imagesc(I) result

Comment: @Geonik So if you look as the x and y axes of the two plots (the image and the plot) they are very different. This is why when you plot them both they don't line up. You'll need to figure out how to scale either the plot or the image to match them up.

Comment: Yes sure this is an issue, but the bigger one is that the image doesn't appear at all

Comment: @Geonik Did you actually zoom into the lower left hand corner of the plot to see if it is there?

Comment: Sorry Suever, you were definitely right! :-) The image is into the lower left corner, so as you said is "just" an axes issue.

Comment: @Geonik You can alter the `XData` and `YData` of the image to shift it within the axes to align it with the other plotted data.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am preaching to the choir or overlooking something here but the example you used actually mapped the image to the data range of the plot, hence the lines:

```
% set the range of the axes
% The image will be stretched to this.
min_x = 0;
max_x = 8;
min_y = 0;
max_y = 6;

imagesc([min_x max_x], [min_y max_y], img);
```

where you directly plot your image

```
imagesc(I);
```

If now your data coordinates and your image coordinates are vastly different you either see one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, I solved in this way:

```
I = imread('orto.png'); % satellite image loading
DEM = GRIDobj('demF1.tif');
FD  = FLOWobj(DEM,'preprocess','c');
S = STREAMobj(FD,flowacc(FD)>1000); % Stream network extraction
x = S.x;    % [node attribute] x-coordinate vector 
y = S.y;    % [node attribute] y-coordinate vector 

min_x = min(x);
max_x = max(x);
min_y = min(y);
max_y = max(y);

imagesc([min_x max_x], [min_y max_y], I);
hold on

plot(S);
```

Here's the resulting image: [stream network over the satellite image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDUSv.jpg)

Actually the stream network doesn't match the satellite image just because I'm temporarily using different images and DEM.